# Escaping special characters in htaccess redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having some issues with a few 301 redirects in htaccess.  The original filenames/URLs were given special characters that I'm not quite sure how to properly escape.  The URLs are structured like:

```
 company%E2%80%99s-person-of-interest-aman%E2%80%99s-most-prestigious-%E2%80%9Cacademy-of-leaders-award%E2%80%9D
```

which equates to:

```
 company’s-person-of-interest-aman’s-most-prestigious-“academy-of-leaders-award”
```

I've tried some things like

```
 company\'-person-of-interest-aman\'s-most-prestigious-\"Cacademy-of-leaders-award\"
```

but that didn't work.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a UTF-8 character, which doesn't equate to \' or \" on the server side because ' and ’ are different characters according to the encoding spec. You could do one of two things:

1) You could simply rename the files, substituting the ASCII compatible characters for the UTF-8 ones

2) Use the percent encoded values in your redirect string directly.

Instead of

```
company\'-person-of-interest-aman\'s-most-prestigious-\"Cacademy-of-leaders-award\"
```

do

```
company%E2%80%99s-person-of-interest-aman%E2%80%99s-most-prestigious-%E2%80%9Cacademy-of-leaders-award%E2%80%9C
```

**EDIT**: while writing the answer, I also realized that your original expression for the redirect url isn't quite matching up even if your characters were ASCII:

```
 company\'-person-of-interest-aman\'s-most-prestigious-\"Cacademy-of-leaders-award\"
```

should be

```
 company\'s-person-of-interest-aman\'s-most-prestigious-\"academy-of-leaders-award\"
```